# How can I Specify Relative Time in UILocalNotification Alert Body (i.e. "starting in X minutes")?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm creating a local notification like this:

```
NSDate *fireDate = // start date from model
NSString *startingInMinutes = @"5 minutes"; // also actually from model    
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your event is starting in %@", startingInMinutes];
notification.fireDate = fireData;
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

After the notification is shown to the user, however, the "5 minutes" string is quickly outdated.

For example, if the user doesn't interact with the notification for 30 minutes, it still shows "Your event is starting in 5 minutes." This is obviously due to the fact that the "5 minutes" is a hard-coded string.

Is there any syntax to specify a relative time (i.e. "in X minutes") in the alert body of a `UILocalNotification`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything about that.
It's a static text.

See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/)

Comment: The documentation does not comment on this. That is, I imagine (if Apple chose to allow such) a relative-time-syntax would work here. AFAIK, I agree this isn't possible, but... prove it. :)

Comment: If you take a look at the properties in the documentation, you'll see that alertBody is of type String for Swift, NSString for objective-c.  So the text can't be dynamic because of this, and this if from the Apple documentation. @JRG-Developer

Comment: So what about the type? Again, it doesn't matter... a syntax-based approach would work, some sort of updating mechanism for this would work, etc... I'm just not finding the right hooks. This may be an interesting insight in itself, but again, it doesn't prove this isn't possible. :)

Comment: _Assign a string or, preferably, a localized-string key (using NSLocalizedString) as the value of the message. If the value of this property is non-nil, an alert is displayed. The default value is nil (no alert). Printf style escape characters are stripped from the string prior to display; to include a percent symbol (%) in the message, use two percent symbols (%%)._  For me, it prove that there is no update mechanism or hidden hook (except maybe private API who are not allowed on AppStore). If there is one, Apple would tell in the doc. Why would't they ?  But it's my point of view about this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible because the notification's payload is set at the time it is scheduled (`UILocationNotification`) or delivered to APNS (remove notification).

You have two choices:

1. Leave your message as is and hope that the user realizes that the content of the message reflects a frozen point in time and can mentally do the math using the notification's timestamp.
2. Adjust the text to be slightly ambiguous ("Your event is starting soon") or reference an absolute time ("Your event starts at 4:00pm").

---

WatchKit does include `WKInterfaceTimer`, which is an OS-controlled counter label.  It was created to decrease the amount of communication needed between an Apple Watch and an iPhone just to update UI as the time changes.  If this functionality is important to you in a notification context, I would encourage you to submit a bug report asking for the enhancement at https://bugreport.apple.com.